# Cisco Anyconnect installation caused wireless adapter to stop working (Can't connect to this network)

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-driver, cisco-vpn-client, wireless-adapter, cisco-anyconnect

I have two windows 10 computers I installed cisco anyconnect mobility client to access my school VPN outside of school, and I've been using ethernet, but once I unplug ethernet and try to connect to any wifi with password or without password I get "Can't connect to this network" error, like it won't even connect to the wifi. I restored one computer to a checkpoint before I installed the cisco client and now the wireless adapter works fine again, so I know it has to do something with the cisco client.

On the current computer with cisco still installed, I found a fix was to actually connect to the wifi network through the client by looking for the wifi and putting the password inside there, but if you try to connect through the computer's menu wifi it won't work. My only concern is the cisco client fked up my wireless adapter driver and the wifi does not seem as fast as the computer without cisco(both not connected to VPN) and I did all the standard fixes for wifi like uninstalling drivers in device manager and scanning hardware changes, network reset, troubleshooter, etc. beforehand.

Another reason why I think it's cisco client is while in system restore u can see what exactly is being affected when I go back to the restore point and interesting enough two drivers have very similar names to my wireless adapter driver, so I think cisco client did something to them but Idk what exactly it did to them.

Comment: Welcome to SU. It looks like you're going around this the wrong way. You need to connect to the Wi-Fi first using the OS tools, then start the VPN client.